# How to install a portable AC exhaust in a vertical window with horizontal blinds?

Tags: air-conditioning

I have a window with a moving vertical part, so to open and close this window I need to slide the moving part left or right. And the window has horizontal blinds on it.

I'd like to install a portable A/C and put its exhaust into this window, but I think the portable A/C exhaust would get in the way of the blinds.

What is the best way to install the exhaust, while keeping the blinds functional and aesthetic?

One of the options I see is to install vertical shades, but if I install them in one window, I would need to replace window blinds to vertical in all the house windows to keep a coherent appearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buy a matching shade and have it cut to the correct length for your application. In the winter, you put the old blind back. Swapping out just the fins might be easier, instead of hanging the new track. You'd have to break it down anyway to store it properly, unless you hang it right back up somewhere (like your garage) and you'd need someone to help you move it.

For the install, I'd cut some 3/4" plywood to fit the opening snugly and core a hole for the exhaust. Lock it in place with a board laying flat along the bottom of the other window. Precision here is also key; you don't want the plywood falling out (or people getting in).

If you're worried about esthetics, buy cabinet grade plywood; it paints up nicely.

Answer (score 0):

With a long enough vertical window adapter kit, you could likely get the exhaust hose port to be at the very bottom of your window. That would let you get your blinds almost all the way down, which might be good enough. There's really not much more you can do -- portable A/C units work best with a direct exhaust route to the outside, so any shenanigans to try and squeeze that exhaust hose between your blinds will reduce its efficiency and lead to sub-par cooling.

You could also use a special, sliding-window A/C unit (e.g. [http://www.amazon.com/Frigidaire-FFRS1022R1-115-volt-Conditioner-Full-Function/dp/B00VV2JV3I](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VV2JV3I)), which might be able to fit behind your blinds.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to integrate horizontal blinds with a portable air conditioner in a vertical window. The exhaust hose is pretty thick and I'd highly recommend getting a dual hose unit, since the single hose ones suck (most of the freshly chilled air out of the room, leading to low pressure and terrible efficiency), so you'll have two thick hoses, one atop the other, so your blinds will come max 60÷ down. However, I've found that there are a lot of decorative car windscreen shades that can cover the gap and not look half bad.